# Reset a folder in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, user-folders

For some reason Thunderbird deleted both my email accounts, I did get them reset, one account repopulated the sub folders I had set up with saved messages. The other account did not repopulate the sub folders.
Anyway to get Thunderbird to reset all the sub-folders I had originally had before the shutdown. 
I can not even figure why it deleted my folders. 
Also I had also run CCcleaner just before this happened however I had run this many times before with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

CCleaner is continually updated -- a previous version might have been OK, and a newer one *not*. Also, Thunderbird has made major changes in moving to v. 68 that could be problematic with CCleaner.

Easiest fix is to restore your profile from your last disk image. There's no need to do a complete disk restore; just the profile folder. **N.B.** Save any emails that are in local folders, made since that backup, to someplace outside the folder, since those would be overwritten on restore.